# Reading binary input in Fortran90

Tags: io, binary, fortran

someone produced an output for me with the following subroutine

```
subroutine write(...)
REAL*8 v(a), h(b), f(b)
integer iv(b+1), jv(a)

 write(ium) a, b, c, d, e
 write(ium) (iv(i),i=1,b+1)
 write(ium) (jv(i),i=1,a)
 write(ium) (v(i),i=1,a)
 write(ium) (f(i),i=1,b)
 write(ium) (h(i),i=1,b)

return
end
```

I know that a, b, c, d and e will all be integers (although the routine doesn't specify them as such, is that okay?!). The whole output went into a binary file which he send to me and I now want to retrieve all the (seperated) information back.

I really don't know much about Fortran I/O so I'm hoping someone can help...

Comment: Nope, because the only info I got on how he wrote the file is this routine...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple example, basically just exchange `write` by `read`. Take care to allocate the arrays first.

```
program test
  implicit none

  integer,parameter   :: ium=1234
  integer             :: a=1, b=2, c=3, d=4, e=5
  REAL*8,allocatable  :: v(:), h(:), f(:)
  integer,allocatable :: iv(:), jv(:)
  integer             :: i, stat

  ! Set values
  allocate( v(a), h(b), f(b), iv(b+1), jv(a), stat=stat )
  if (stat/=0) stop 'Cannot allocate memory!'

  v=1.d0
  h=2.d0
  f=3.d0
  iv = 4
  jv = 5

  write(*,*) v, h, f

  ! Write back
  open(unit=ium, file='test',form='unformatted',status='replace',action='write')

  write(ium) a, b, c, d, e
  write(ium) (iv(i),i=1,b+1)
  write(ium) (jv(i),i=1,a)
  write(ium) (v(i),i=1,a)
  write(ium) (f(i),i=1,b)
  write(ium) (h(i),i=1,b)

  close(ium)

  ! Scratch
  deallocate( v, h, f, iv, jv )

  !========================================
  ! Read in
  open(unit=ium, file='test',form='unformatted',status='old',action='read')

  read(ium) a, b, c, d, e
  ! Allocate arrays
  allocate( v(a), h(b), f(b), iv(b+1), jv(a), stat=stat )
  if (stat/=0) stop 'Cannot allocate memory!'

  read(ium) (iv(i),i=1,b+1)
  read(ium) (jv(i),i=1,a)
  read(ium) (v(i),i=1,a)
  read(ium) (f(i),i=1,b)
  read(ium) (h(i),i=1,b)

  close(ium)
  write(*,*) v, h, f

  deallocate( v, h, f, iv, jv )
end program
```

Adjust this to your needs.

Comment: +1 -- worth a note "unformatted" fortran is not nescesaritly platform portable, so if this fails you may need to dig deeper. (and it is not an advisable way to exchange data )